# jQuery: randomise mouse speed for each div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a setup where divs follow the cursor around the screen (currently 2 divs but this will be content managed so there's soon to be dozens of them), ideally each div following the cursor at a different speed (with a maximum speed of 50).
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/nEKgN/

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY);
});

var follower = $(".stuck");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 30;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 30;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY);
});

var follower = $(".stuck-2");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 20;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 20;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
});
```

In the example above I've had to give each div a different class (or ID) to set a different speed for each one, but like I say as this is going to be content managed this will be impossible, ideally I'd like all the divs to have the same class and randomize the speed for every one, with a maximum speed of 50. Can't figure out if this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.each` to iterate over the followers and assign each a "jump" value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0;
    $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
        mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX);
        mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY);
    });

    var followers = $(".stuck");

    followers.each(function () {
        var follower = $(this),
            jump = 1 + (Math.random() * 50),
            xp = 0,
            yp = 0;

        var loop = setInterval(function () {
            // higher is slower
            xp += (mouseX - xp) / jump;
            yp += (mouseY - yp) / jump;
            follower.css({
                left: xp,
                top: yp
            });
        }, 30);
    });

});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Nxdm7/

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after, thanks for that. One small question, not mega important but it's something I am looking to implement, is it possible for a function like this to work on mobile devices? i.e. following your finger touch around the screen?

Comment: @user1374796 Yes. You would use the appropriate touch analogue to `mousemove`, but otherwise the code wouldn't change at all.